# In Spacemacs, how do I enable web-mode .blade.php files?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

What should I put in .spacemacs so that `web-mode` will be enabled instead of `php-mode` for `.blade.php` files in Laravel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the following in your **$HOME/.spacemacs** file, in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.blade.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

Comment: user-init sounds fine. I'm not an expert on spacemacs, but you can put it just about anywhere and it'll be fine.

Comment: i put it in user-config. it didnt work when i put it in user-init though.